# PHP/Apache - Migrating session from server to browser

Tags: php, apache

So if I use a server to make call to web page (cURL or file_get_contents or something), and that web page assigns a session to that call (like I use that call to add an item to a shopping cart), is it possible to then migrate that session to a user's browser from the server?

Comment: What do you mean in regards to migrating a session from server to browser?  Do you want shopping cart information, or session id information?  What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want your server code to browse to a separate site behind the scenes, do something there that creates a session, and then redirect the user of your app to that separate site, but using the same session you created.

If the session is maintained using a cookie, as is likely, than no, you can't -- you'd have to set the cookie in the user's browser as if it came from that other site, and you can't.  In general, this seems like it would be prevented by any sort of session hijacking protection, which most decent sites do have.

The alternative, I suppose, is to proxy for your user for their entire use of that other site (i.e. they click on stuff in your app and you pass it on to the other site behind the scenes).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right.  I didn't think it would work but thought I'd double check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use simpletest's scriptable browser ( http://simpletest.sourceforge.net/en/browser_documentation.html ) to keep track of states while browsing the interwebs form your PHP codez

Answer (score 0):

Probably not - That call to cURL / `file_get_contents` will likely generate specific session information for the machine that requested it (i.e. your server). The remote machine should be keeping track of things like IP address and other identifiable information to prevent such a maneuver.

If this is possible, then your shopping cart software is horrifically vulnerable to session hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible.  But you can start a session between the user's browser and your server, which keeps track of the session cookie that the remote web page issues you.